# Get value from a percentage from a range of 2 numbers

Tags: php

For example I have this range:

20 to 200

How can I programmatically get the value for a specific percentage, lets say 40% between those 2 numbers?

Simple example:

0 to 200

I want to get the value of 40%. Answer is 80.

Comment: 200-20 is 180, 40% of that is 72, add the 20 again – result is 92. (If that’s what you are looking for.)

Comment: thank you CBroe! this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$num1=20;
$num2=200;
$percent=40;
$total=$num2-$num1;
$result = (($total/100) * $percent)+$num1;
```

Comment: No semi-colon at the end of line 3. Would result in an error.

Comment: My mistake thanks i will update it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function percentage_from_range($from, $to, $percentage) {
    $result = (($to - $from) / 100 * $percentage) + $from;
    return $result;
}
```

e.g.

```
echo percentage_from_range(20, 200, 40); //92
```

Comment: you need to add $from imho

Comment: @mnagel range from `20` to `200` is `180`, `1%` from `180` is `1.8`, `40%` is `72`

Comment: yeah sure but i think it supposed to be used as in "what number is 50% of the 'distance' from 80 to 120" --> expected answert: 100.

Comment: @mnagel I see what you mean, updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$lwb = 20;
$upb = 200;
$perc = 40;

$value = $lwb + ($upb - $lwb) * $perc / 100;
```

Takes perc/100 part of range, and start with the lowerbound.

Comment: The result of the code above will be wrong because of MDAS rule. `*` will be executed before `/`. Should have parenthesis on `$perc / 100`. Thanks Joop!

Comment: Fortunately `a*b/c == (a*b)/c == a*(b/c)`, but I indeed explained it as the second.